# How to choose a wrap (station) antenna for space application?

Tags: antenna, space, satellite, aerospace

I am looking for my research project a wrap (station) antenna. It is assumed that the antenna works in space (lunar) environment. The total dose for my device is 30 – 50 krad. Gain 3-5 dBi. Frequency is S band.

1. Does anyone know of what the antenna should be made of?
2. If an antenna operates in +40 to +85, can I use it or is it important material it made of?
3. Fiberglass antenna, will be it work in lunar surface?

**EDIT 1  Wrap station antenna. Omni**

[image]

Comment: do you mean a "wrap-around antenna"? Material always matters: An antenna made of cheese might sound clever on the moon, but will not work well at +85°C, and even at room temperature is very lossy. No antennas are made of fiberglass; the mechanical carrier for the antenna might.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added a picture of a wrap antenna  i mean

Comment: @MarcusMüller LORA FIBERGLASS OUTDOOR ANTENNA WITH CABLE : 
 https://www.antratek.de/lora-fiberglass-outdoor-antenna-with-cable?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInvOu7-K79gIVSRV7Ch2JRgRbEAQYDyABEgI5F_D_BwE

Comment: that's a marketing name. The antenna in the electrical engineering sense isn't made of fiberglass. The housing is. I don't know why you'd want this – is there any atmosphere or other particles you need to worry about on your antenna? What's the technical motivation here? As even the product description says, the fiberglass housing is against rain and moisture. Of all the problems you have on moon, these are of lesser concern!

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh no. I sont plan to use a fiberglass antenna for my project. I sont know what antenna I can use for my application. i dont think that only operating temperature is important for me. material is more important, becouse a plastic device doesnt work in space

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva PTFE and PEEK are both plastics that work in space. You won't find any normal antenna that is housed using them though because on Earth other materials work for 1/100th the cost.

Comment: citation needed, a lot of the internals and externals of rovers are made of plastics

Comment: Are you planning to launch a screw terminal antenna to the moon? Who is paying for it?

Comment: `antenna operates in +40 to +85` ...  +40 of what?

Comment: In most space missions, every gram of added weight has to be justified. The plastic and fiberglass in that antenna add weight. But what purpose will it serve on the Moon? (There's no weather on the Moon, and your mission may have bigger problems if you have to worry about protection from impacts and abrasion.)  The detachable connector adds weight. But, who is going to attach and detach it on the Moon? Also, the plastic probably will [_outgas_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing) in the vacuum of space, which may cause problems for other components of your spacecraft.

Comment: @jsotola temperature, C

Comment: Sounds like a very hot day on the moon.

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva your post still says `antenna operates in +40 to +80` ... why have you not corrected it? ... it is difficult to take a research project seriously if it does not include units of measurement